# Sound on my new Gigabyte Z170 Gaming K3 motherboard

Tags: debian, audio

I just upgraded my motherboard from an old one (for Core 2 Quad CPUs) to Gigabyte Z170 Gaming K3 motherboard (which comes with an i5 Skylake CPU) and sound stopped working. I don't get any error messages, but I can't hear anything. I am confident that hardware is OK, because it works in Windows.

```
ga@grzes:~$ sudo alsactl init  
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC1150" "HDA:10ec0900,1458a182,00100001" "0x1458" "0xa182"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

How can I get it to work? I am running latest Debian stable amd64.

Answer (score 0):

Run `alsamixer` in a terminal, then unmute (M) and level up (up arrow) all playback controls on all recognized cards (F6).